# How to see input prompt before requesting it in python3

Tags: python, input

I've been having trouble taking input and no matter what I look at, it shows it should work, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong here.

```
x = input("enter name")
print(x)
```

This is all I have in my test.py, and when I run it, it shows me nothing, then when I enter a prompt and hit enter, it shows the input prompt

(My terminal)

- python -3 test.py
- a (I input this)
- enter first numa (what I receive back)

But what I see everywhere shows that I should be getting that prompt first! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: by prompt, are your referring to the terminal?

Comment: Yes, I'm using git bash as my terminal

Answer (score 0):

i think your code is okay but it's the way you run it is wrong. you should try `python test.py` in your terminal not `python -3 test.py`.

You should navigate to the file and run `python test.py`.

Comment: This did not work either unfortunately, I tried running it on visual studio code terminal and it did however, so I guess it must have been a problem with my terminal

Comment: if you are using windows try running code in `powershell` not cmd. :)